# Match parent width after inflating view

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have 2 `EditText` views in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white">
<MyProject.MyView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        style="@style/my_style"
        android:hint="my hint2"/>
```

Here is the code for `MyProject.MyView`

```
public class MyView : LinearLayout
{
    // not important code...

    public LinearLayout Panel { get; private set; }

    // Gets called from the constructor:
    private void Init()
    {
        var layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.LayoutInflaterService);

        this.content = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.my_content, this.Panel, true);

        this.AddView(this.content);
    }
}
```

And here is `my_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
style="@style/my_style2">
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/my_style"
        android:hint="my hint">

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first `EditText` (that's being inflated from my `MyView` class) won't match the parent's width, it will only wrap the content. But the second `EditText` matches the parent's width. Why?

Comment: What is your `this.content` in class `MyView`?

Comment: It is a `Android.Views.View`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by wrapping the `<LinearLayout>` with a `<RelativeLayout>` in my `my_content` xml. I'm not sure why this was needed, so I would still appreciate an explanation so that I can better understand  the way Android works.

Comment: This worked for me too, I used the inflater in my listview and called to inflate a custom footer textview. Wrapping it with a relativelayout expanded the clickable area.